# tf.less is not supported in tensorflow lite - how to tackle it

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I use tensorflow to train my model, subsequently convert it to tensorflow lite model, but when running it shows that `tf.less`, `tf.greaterthan` are not supported. How should I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Found this updated [python_api.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md)

I was facing similar issues and used this:
    import tensorflow as tf

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_keras_model_file("keras_model.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

This conversion method worked me.

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported ops are available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md). The two recommended solutions are:

1. Add a custom op as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/custom_operators.md).
2. Only use the ops that are currently supported by TFLite in your model.

Comment: BTW, TensorFlow Lite now already supports greater / less (change was done in May)